# Can I access a file saved in internal memory from a Fragment?

Tags: android

I have a file saved in internal memory and I access it like:

```
getApplicationContext().openFileInput("database.xml");
```

But, application context is only limited to Activity classes. So, I was wondering if there is a way to access those files from Fragments?

Comment: Yes, there are many answers here on how to get a valid Context for retrieving information like this.  Note that you need the Context only to *discover* the path - to *access* the file once you know where it is, all you possibly need are the rights granted by running as your application's userid.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Activities Context with `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Be sure to call that after `onAttach(Activity)` was called